# Адрес this сходного класса при виртуальное наследование

Tags: наследование, c++

Есть вот такой простой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class B{
private:
    int j;//если у класса не будет переменных, то "this B" бует равен "this A"
public:
    B(){
        printf("this B=%d\n",(int)this);
    }
};

class A:public virtual B{
public:
    A(){
        printf("this A=%d\n",(int)this);
    }
};

int main(){
    A*a=new A();
    delete a;
}
</code>
```

Результат выполнения:

```
this B=147431436
this A=147431432
```

из результата видно, что this для класса B это НЕ одно и тоже что this для класса A.
Если наследование будет НЕ виртуальным, то адреса совпадут. Так же, если в классе B не будет параметров, то адреса тоже совпадут.

Но вот сейчас пример (с виртуальным наследованием и параметрами) и адреса не совпадают. Можно каким-то образом из класса B получить указатель на объект A? т.е. нужно что бы класс B явно знал адрес всего того экземпляра, наследником которого он является

Comment: Тут есть немного на эту тему http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%2B%2B в разделе "Полиморфизм и множественное наследование"

Comment: С какой целью вам нужен доступ к потомку? Просто для подобных задач правильнее использовать либо *защищённый чисто виртуальный метод*, либо *шаблон проектирования «посетитель»*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Можно каким-то образом из класса B получить указатель на объект A?

```
A*a = dynamic_cast< A* >( this );
```

Для неполиморфных классов подойдет:

```
A*a = static_cast< A* >( this );
```

только этот вызов нужно делать после объявления класса `A`, например в `cpp` или `inlin'ом`, ниже объявления класса `A`.

> т.е. нужно что бы класс B явно знал адрес всего того экземпляра, наследником которого он является

Т.е., я правильно понимаю? Вы хотите из класса `B` выделить не просто `A`, Вы хотите из класса `B` выделить самого дальнего потомка - корень дерева наследования?

В общем случае, средствами языка эта задача неразрешима: **предки не должны контролировать цепочку потомков.**

Но, тем не менее, лет 5-7 назад, я такое делал. В двух словах: пишется утилитка для `visual studio`, которая выделяет `RTTI` из всех объектных файлов перед этапом линковки. Выстраивает цепочку потомков для каждого скомпилированного символа:

```
template< typename Base, typename Type >
struct RTTI_Base{
  static Base Type::**Offsets;
  static INT Count;
};
```

cоздает дополнительную секцию в таком объектном файле, и подставляет адреса из нее для каждого `RTTI_Base< Base, Type >::Offsets`.

`RTTI_Base` - это как бы запрос к этой утилите на получение цепочки потомков, из заданного класса `Type`, которые имеют базу `Base`, т.е. порождены от какого-то интерфейса `Base`.

Это все конечно интересно, но, поигравшись с таким посткомпилятором на разных наборах классов, "забросил его в чулан" за ненадобностью. В обычной жизни такое не нужно.

Comment: Вот такая ошибка:
../src/main.cpp:26:33: ошибка: cannot dynamic_cast «this» (of type «class B* const») to type «class A*» (source type is not polymorphic)

Компилю GCC'ом 4.6.3

Comment: `source type is not polymorphic` - да, это говорящая ошибка. Означает, что `A` не имеет ни каких дескрипторов наследования, на которые ориентируется `dynamic_cast`. Дайте этим классам какие-нибудь виртуальные методы. Для неполиморфных классов подойдет A*a = static_cast< A* >( this );

Comment: В классе B добавил метод virtual void test()=0; в классе A дописал virtual void test()=0;

в итоге A*a = dynamic_cast< A* >( this ); компилируется, но переменная "a" равна нулю

Comment: Используйте `static_cast`, он в этом случае надежнее. Скорее всего, у Вас оптимизация съела полиморфизм.

Comment: Оптимизация выключена.
Сейчас записал A*a = static_cast< A* >( this );

в итоге вот такая ошибка:
ошибка преобразования базового «B» в производный тип «A» через виртуальный базовый тип «B»

Comment: >ошибка преобразования базового «B» в производный тип «A» через виртуальный базовый тип «B»

А зачем Вам здесь виртуальное наследование?

Answer (score 1):

Несколько раз прочел, да так и не понял **что** требуется, а главное **для чего**. Думается надо-бы поменять подход к задаче.
По сабжу на ум приходит трюк со страннорекуррентным шаблоном (Curiously Reccuring Template Pattern)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//предполагаем что наследник будет передавать себя в качестве шаблона
//таким образом знаем тип наследника
template<class Child>
class Base
{
public:
    void print() const
    {
        //не уверен в валидности static_cast
        static_cast<const Child*> (this)->printChild();
    }
};

class Derived: public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    void printChild() const
    {
        cout <<"Child"<<endl;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    Derived* d = new Derived;
    d->print();
}
```

[Расположение полиморфных объектов в памяти](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/storage-layout-of-polymorphic-objects/240012098) поможет понять что к чему с полиморфными типами

Comment: Так вот она какая, эта ООПа! "И эти люди запрещают мне ковырять в носу!" (c) Вовочка.