# Получить параметры функций

Tags: c++, функции

Использую в программе систему перевода с применением функции `Lang("Text")`, которая возвращает найденный перевод строки, либо переданный текст. По ходу вызовов `Lang()` программа заносит новые слова в файл.

Как бы получить сразу все тексты во всех `Lang()`? Подозреваю, вариант с применением `#define` и хитрым кодом. Хотя как вариант можно прогнать код программы через парсер.

Comment: Что значит `сразу все тексты во всех Lang()`? МБ пример кода представите и вопрос на его основе сформулируете?

Comment: В программе куча вызовов Lang("--help print this help"), Lang("options");, Lang("someone save us"); ...
Задача - собрать все тексты содержащиеся в них.

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужны все вхождения "Text" в коде программы. Раньше можно было в шаблонах указывать адреса статических переменных. т.е., в Вашем случае, можно бы было завернуть все вхождения "Text" в макрос `_D`:

 #define _D( x ) TextNode< x >::Text
 
 struct Node{
   static const Node*Root = NULL;
   const char*Text
   const Node*Next;
   operator const char*( void )const{ return Text; }
   Node( const char*Text ) : Text( Text ), Next( Root ){
     Root = this;
   }
 }
 
 template< char*T >
 struct TextNode{
   static const Node Text = T;
 };
Результирующий список в Node::Root

Comment: Не получается запустить. MS VS говорит: Ошибка 15 error C2864: TextNode<T>::Text: в пределах класса могут быть инициализированы только статические константные данные-члены целого типа

Comment: В качестве параметра шаблона можно передавать указатель только объектов, созданных в глобальной области видимости, т.е. тех объектов, чей адрес известен во время компиляции.

Comment: А вообще вопрос сформулировать совершенно неопределенно и нечетко.

Comment: А почему просто не прогнать исходники проекта через grep?

Comment: >Ошибка 15 error C2864: TextNode<T>::Text: в пределах класса могут быть инициализированы только статические константные данные-члены целого типа

@mikelsv, я код не проверял, но если вы решите его локальные проблемы, скорее всего доведете до комментария @mikillskegg, с характерной ошибкой.

>В качестве параметра шаблона можно передавать указатель только объектов, созданных в глобальной области видимости, т.е. тех объектов, чей адрес известен во время компиляции.

@mikillskegg, поэтому я не ответил, а прокомментировал :)

Comment: @mega, честно говоря я все равно не понял, как это решение привязать к моей задаче. В результате действия макроса получится строка "LangMarkersomeone save us".

Comment: @mega, я опять не вижу способа привязки к программе. Как получить этот список?

Comment: @VladD, у меня кончились комментарии в ответе.
Строка на которой работает неправильно:
print("\t\t", Lang("--help print this help"), "\r\n");

Comment: error C2448: lang: вероятно, инициализатор, использующий стиль 

функции, является определением функции.

VS.

Comment: >Эээ нет! Если вы требуете, чтобы все аргументы Lang были константами, обёрнутыми в _D (возможно, не прямо, а косвенно), то это ничем вообще не отличается от требования, чтобы просто все аргументы Lang были константами -- просто переименуйте Lang -> Lang1 и _D -> Lang. А для случая константных аргументов катит и простой парсер на sed. :)

Ну вот, опять Вы вернулись к исходной точке: Вы не развернете **одним** фильтром все вхождения `Lang`, а я даже разворачивать не буду, за меня все сделает компилятор. Вот в этом и вся суть.

Comment: @mega: подождите, значит, мы с вами накладываем условие, что все аргументы Lang (ну или _D, если вам так больше нравится) -- константы? Если да, то мой фильтр прекрасно всё "разворачивает". Если нет, то заменив в Challenge Lang на _D, получим, что и ваш код не сработает. Верно? (У меня и тут заканчиваются комментарии.)

Comment: >значит, мы с вами накладываем условие, что все аргументы Lang (ну или _D, если вам так больше нравится) -- константы?

Это условие наложил @mikelsv, т.к. он хочет получить все тексты, которые могут встретиться в программе, при передаче их в `Lang`.

>Если да, то мой фильтр прекрасно всё "разворачивает".

Ну, я же привел примеры, посмотрите мой отредактированный ответ.

Если нет, то заменив в Challenge Lang на _D, получим, что и ваш код не сработает. Верно? (У меня и тут заканчиваются комментарии.)

Мой сработает, т.к. критерий "при передаче их в `Lang`" я заменил на "помечен маркером".

Comment: @mikelsv: спасибо за вопрос, у нас вышел замечательный (без иронии) флейм в ответах :)

Comment: @VladD, (делаю комментарий здесь, т.к. это "горячее" в настоящий момент место в обсуждении).

IMHO sed-ом (и т.п.) задачу не решить, даже обрабатывая вывод gcc -E. Посмотрите:

        Lang("abc"
        /* comment */
             "cde");

да, препроцессор уберет комментарий, но оставит пустую строку, а для компиилятора это ОК. Потом печатается

    abccde

Не знаю, как с макросами. Насколько я понял их надо вставить всюду в текст программы внуть Lang? Такая идея мало кому из пишущих код понравится.

Поэтому без парсера тут не обойтись.

Comment: @mega: какой из примеров вы имеете в виду? `#define MyLng( x ) Lang( x )`? Это противоречит заданию -- искать надо _текст_ Lang(...), MyLng и т. п. Мы же договорились не расширять задание. Для констант моё замечание с Challenge отпадает. Но представьте себе, что у нас есть код:

    if (random(4) < 0) { cout << Lang("1") }

Компилятор знает, что значение `random` положительное, и выкидывает код при оптимизации. Завтра приходит разработчик, находит ошибку и исправляет её. Запускать анализ снова?

Comment: @VladD, `#define MyLng( x ) Lang( x )` легко решается вызовом препроцессора.

А компилятор ничего не знает и знать не будет о `random()` (самое большее, что он может себе позволить это выдать warning о функциях типа `gets()` и форматах `printf()`).

--

IMHO вас с @mega куда-то занесло. Наверняка автору просто лень руками (grep + любимый редактор) сделать список сообщений программы для документации.

Answer (score 3):

Для `Windows`, я бы решил эту проблему аналогично, как в ситуации: ["Построение цепочки потомков для каждого скомпилированного символа"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166129#166133), при условии, что макрос `_D` выглядел бы как-то так:

```
#define ___D( x ) #x
#define __D( marker, x ) ___D( marker ## x )
#define _D( x ) __D( LangMarker, x )
```

при том, что `marker` более ни где по коду в тексте встречаться не будет. И, соответственно, использовался бы он так:

```
Lang( _D( someone save us ) );
```

Хотя, именно для такой задачи, "овчинка выделки не стоит".

Можно даже вырезать из всех этих строк **сам маркер**! Т.е. маркер будет выступать в роли **`compile-time`-атрибута**, предписывающего размещение строки в таком массиве, но это реализовать уже сложнее, т.к. потребует модификации всех ссылок на эти строки.

Можно **в самом маркере закодировать переменную, в которую будет сливаться такой массив**. Т.е, на самом деле, вариантов, как это реализовать в `compile-time` достаточно много и может ограничиваться только фантазией и возможностями самого языка.

**Мои комментарии везде позаканчивались, поэтому я выбрал из своих ответов тот, который бы решал поставленную задачу.** Некоторые зависимые от него комментарии я так же переместил в тело ответа, чтобы была понятна их связь. Следите, пожалуйста, за моими новыми комментариями при редактировании ответа. К сожалению, более подходящего решения оставлять сообщения в форуме я пока не вижу. Думаю, стоит этот вопрос вынести на рассмотрение администрации.

**Комментарии:**

> как это решение привязать к моей задаче

@mikelsv, это решение включает в себя "посткомпилятор", который найдет все строки в объектных файлах и выделит из них только те, которые помечены маркером. Организует из них список или вектор и поместит адрес его первого элемента в какую-нибудь статическую переменную. **Все это он сделает на этапе компиляции**, поэтому в программе вектор/список строк будет известен заранее, можно даже знать его размер заранее.

> Если вы говорите о синтаксисе времени выполнения, то не гарантировано, что любая из конструкций `Lang()` вообще когда-либо сработает или вообще произведёт код

Я не говорю о синтаксисе времени выполнения, я говорю о `compile-time` выражениях, которые допустимы в `statement'е` параметра функции.

> компиляция может до макроса `Lang` вообще не добраться. Например:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
    Lang("1")
#else
    Lang("2")
#endif
```

Тогда это будет зависимая конструкция. Значит, в реальной программе эта конструкция и не встретится никогда без перекомпиляции с `SOMETHING`.

> Так что рантайм и компиляция не кажется мне адекватным решением

Не уверен, что в адекватности дело.

> @mega: не, так нельзя рассуждать. Потому что если я перед функцией `main` напишу

```
int doexit() { exit(0); return 0; }
int i = doexit();
```

> то рантайм ни до одного `Lang` не доберётся. Чем это отличается от `#ifdef`? Ничем, просто другой синтаксис.

@VladD, как это соотносится с условием задачи? От #ifdef это отличается тем, что до `Lang` исполнение просто не доберется. Поэтому, если компилятор учитывает особенности `ОС`и, он и формировать не будет "недосягаемый" код.

> Ergo: в рантайме вы не можете гарантированно добраться до содержимого Lang.

У меня другой вопрос: **а зачем Вам "недосягаемый" `Lang`?**
Ведь Вы можете написать:

```
#define MyLng( x ) Lang( x )
```

и везде в программе использовать `MyLng`, что в таком случае будете делать? Очевидно, будете править свой фильтр, "раздувать" `regexp` для `Lang`, и возможно, все будет хорошо, если не забудете, о каком-нибудь еще аналоге `MyLng` :)

Или можете поступить интереснее:

```
#define __Depend( x ) #x
#define _Depend( x, y ) x ##<-depend <-## y
#define Depend( x, y ) __Depend( _Depend( x, y ) )

Lang( Depend( head, neck ) )
Lang( Depend( head, _Depend( neck, body ) ) )
```

Очевидно, в такой ситуации очередное "раздувание" `regexp` будет частично включать код самого макроса `Depend`, все его возможные вложения и, соответственно все зависимости, которые из него вытекают. Т.е., у Вас и с досягаемым-то кодом уже проблемы, а Вы о недосягаемом думаете, странно :)

По моему, **один** парсер ( а в нашем случае, лучше сказать - "сканер" ) эту задачу не решит. Вернее, суть его решения всегда будет заключаться в том, **как бы переписать фильтр под конкретный код**. А это означает, что человек, который его использует, при изменении кода, всегда будет сталкиваться с исходной проблемой, т.е. он ее так и не решит.

Периодически, я с такими решениями тоже сталкиваюсь. Тот же `doxygen` - полезнейший продукт, но абсолютно "тупой" парсер. Вот и ему приходится расписывать в `PREDEFINED` десятки элементарных фильтров и следить за их обновлениями.

> Не знаю, как с макросами. Насколько я понял их надо вставить всюду в текст программы внуть Lang? Такая идея мало кому из пишущих код понравится.

@avp, макрос нужен только для фильтрации строк, т.е., чтобы в массиве были только определенные константные строки, а не все, что были скомпилированы. Ну, допустим, самый простой вариант: все строки в Lang будут начинаться с `##`, например: `Lang( "##someone save us" )`. Т.е. нужна какая-то идентификация самих строк. Если она уже есть, значит и код менять не потребуется.

Либо, как вариант: **все эти строки будут находиться в определенном сегменте памяти (секции)**, тогда модификации кода будут вообще минимальны. Я сейчас не могу сказать, в каком классе данных находятся константные строки `VS`, надо разобрать для примера какой-нибуть `*.obj`, со строками. Но в любом случае, это контролируется прагмой `data_seg` или `code_seg`, поэтому, заключив функцию/класс/заголовок и т.п., который содержит **массовые вызовы `Lang`** в определенный сегмент, его можно будет использовать в качестве фильтра, который будет отделять обычные строки от искомых.

> Поэтому без парсера тут не обойтись.

Во во, и я о том же. А что может быть лучше парсера от `VS`? Наверное только парсер от `VS`, его-то мы и используем. Нам ведь не сам парсер нужен. Нам нужны результаты его работы. В `*.obj` и находятся результаты его работы.

> @mega: какой из примеров вы имеете в виду? #define MyLng( x ) Lang( x )? Это противоречит заданию -- искать надо текст Lang(...)

`MyLng` как раз и делает вызов `Lang(...)`. Как это может противоречить заданию?

> Но представьте себе, что у нас есть код:

```
if (random(4) < 0) { cout << Lang("1") }
```

> Компилятор знает, что значение random положительное, и выкидывает код при оптимизации. Завтра приходит разработчик, находит ошибку и исправляет её. Запускать анализ снова?

Даже если представить, что Компилятор делает какие-то предположения по поводу этой функции. Разработчик, исправив ошибку **запустит процесс сборки заново**. Т.е. запустит всю цепочку утилит компоновки, в которую входят все задействованные компиляторы, **мой "посткомпилятор" (или "прелинкер")**, и, непосредственно линковщик. Что с того? Будет массив на один элемент длиннее, что от этого изменится? Или Вы переживаете на счет того, что количество "билдов" программы увеличится? Не совсем я понимаю Вашу позицию. Вы ее проясните пожалуйста, а то, подозреваю, ее не только я не понимаю.

Comment: @mega: смотрите. Как ваша конструкция обработает такое:

    void Challеnge(char* s) { cout << Lang(s) << endl; }

? Я пытаюсь выразить и подкрепить примерами мысль о том, что вы в принципе не сможете никак поймать _все возможные_ в рантайме аргументы Lang.

Comment: @mega: код, который недосягаем сегодня, может быть досягаем через неделю. `int doexit() { if (today == friday 13th) exit(0); return 0; }`.

Comment: >Я пытаюсь выразить и подкрепить примерами мысль о том, что вы в принципе не сможете никак поймать все возможные в рантайме аргументы Lang

А я не пытаюсь поймать рантайм, я пишу только о `compile-time`.

>код, который недосягаем сегодня, может быть досягаем через неделю. int doexit() { if (today == friday 13th) exit(0); return 0; }.

А это уже досягаемый код, не надо путать!

Comment: @mega: воот! А компилятор имеет право выбросить всё, что, как он может доказать, не встретится в рантайме. Правильно? (Оффтопик: [вот](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html) статья по теме.) Так что compile-time в принципе не может быть достаточно.

Comment: >А компилятор имеет право выбросить всё, что, как он может доказать, не встретится в рантайме. Правильно?

Конечно! Поэтому я опять повторяю вопрос: зачем Вам код, который не участвует в работе программы, который не влияет на ее поведение?

Comment: @mega: хорошо, а как всё же с `Challenge`?

Comment: >хорошо, а как всё же с Challenge?
Если вы передадите в `Challenge` строку, помеченную маркером, то она появится в списке, но если вы передадите туда что-то `Runtime`, то это что-то в `Runtime` и нужно ловить. @mikillskegg, кстати это и делает. Только Вы с `Challenge` уже в любом случае ничего не сделаете, не добавив его в фильтр.

Answer (score 1):

Вы под Юниксом? Попробуйте просто

```
grep -rh 'Lang(' projectDir/ | sed 's/Lang(/\n\0/g' | grep 'Lang(' | sed 's/^.*Lang(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/' | sort -u >out.txt
```

(Надеюсь, нигде не напутал. Пусть гуру шелла поправят.)

Comment: Вывело в не совсем корректном виде. Парсер я напишу, чтобы не зависеть от платформы и сразу формировать файл в правильном формате. Но сначала хотелось бы сделать это силами языка.

Comment: @mikelsv, Вы собираетесь написать парсер С++?

Comment: @avp, здесь достаточно обычного парсера. Парсер с++ у меня тоже есть.

Comment: Стало лучше, но скрипт не учитывает два Lang() на одной строчке и не убирает другой код. В результате выходит непонятно что: print("\t\t", "--help print this help"), "\r\n";

Comment: @mikelsv: да, и правда, не учитывалось, виноват. Но теперь уж точно должно сработать :)

Comment: `MS VS` под Юниксом? Это нонсенс :)

Comment: @mega: тем не менее, ТС вполне смог опробовать скрипт. За что минус? Скрипт рабочий.

Comment: @VladD
Уже лучше, но есть недоработки: "--help print this help"), "\r\n".

Нужно брать текст до первой закрывающей скобки.

Comment: @mikelsv: не могу воспроизвести проблему. Напишите строчку, на которой неправильно, а?

Comment: Я не считаю, что парсер решит эту задачу полностью. Любой "дефайн" или конкатенация строк в пределах `statement'а` параметра и/или с `predefined macros` нарушит условия фильтрации. Появится видимость того, что фильтр работает, который на самом деле будет пропускать нераскрытые вхождения.

Comment: @mega: это смотря как определять синтаксис задачи. мой синтаксис -- строка Lang(.*). Если вы говорите о синтаксисе времени выполнения, то не гарантировано, что любая из конструкций Lang() вообще когда-либо сработает или вообще произведёт код -- понимаете, почему?

Answer (score 1):

Если я все-таки правильно понял задачу. Сделать синглетон-обертку для контейнера, например, множества std::set (или наследовать его)  и заносить туда в функции Lang() все тексты, которые были переданы ей. Всегда можно прочитать содержимое этого контейнера.

Comment: В задаче нужно прочитать все параметры переданные в Lang() не вызывая данную функцию. В самой функции я и сам могу сохранять переданный текст, и сейчас так и делаю.

Наверно самая подходящая формулировка: считать параметры передаваемые в функцию, не вызывая ее. Задача на знание возможностей языка.

Comment: Нужно определить во время компилирования? Это возможно только если все передаваемые аргументы  - константы.

Comment: Они вроде константы. Обычный текст. Но как это сделать, я не понял. Написал парсер, 20 строчек кода в общем-то решают проблему приемлемым образом.

Comment: >Написал парсер, 20 строчек кода в общем-то решают проблему приемлемым образом.

А что Вы понимаете под словом "парсер"? Можно посмотреть код?

Comment: @mega, не уверен, что код много скажет. Код получает список файлов в папке с расширением cpp, c, h. В файле ищет вхождение Lang(" и "). Текст между ними сохраняет в файл. Единственная проверка - на \ перед закрывающей ".

Comment: >Код получает список файлов в папке с расширением cpp, c, h. В файле ищет вхождение Lang(" и "). Текст между ними сохраняет в файл.

Понятно. Я просто подумал, что Вы написали в 20 строк парсер `Си/Си++` :)

>@mega, я опять не вижу способа привязки к программе. Как получить этот список?

@mikelsv, у меня хватает квалификации, чтобы написать Вам такой посткомпилятор, но Вы не сможете мне оплатить время, которое я на него потрачу. Поэтому, пока ни чем не могу помочь, к сожалению. И я даже не о деньгах сейчас говорю, просто это не та задача, которая стоит этого времени.